# ARSS is throwing Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, spectrogram

So basically, I've just downloaded ARSS (Analysis & Reconstruction Sound Spectrograph, http://arss.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) using homebrew.

However, every time I input a WAV file (44100 Hz, PCM 16 bits signed, mono), it shows:

```
MacBook-Pro:Audio 23rohanb$ arss BLIN.wav
The Analysis & Resynthesis Sound Spectrograph 0.2.3
Input file : BLIN.wav
Output file : h.bmp
Segmentation fault: 11
```

When I type `type arss` I get `arss is hashed (/usr/local/bin/arss)`. I have also tried with 32 bits signed (which returns `This WAVE file format is not currently supported`) as well as stereo for both 16 and 32 bits (no effect).

I've encountered like 6 other problems before stopping here. I'm really tired and decided to turn to the public community. Thanks!

Comment: What does `type arss` tell you? And `file BLIN.wav`? And `mdls BLIN.wav`? Have you tried a stereo sample with a different number of bits?

Comment: Please paste answers to my questions in your question - not in the **comments** where they are unformatted and difficult to read. Thanks.

Comment: Program doesn't seem to have been updated in over 10 years, and the latest note on the home page says it's been superseded by [Photosounder](https://photosounder.com). Also this isn't a programming question so it probably belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for all your help. However, I found a new library called libROSA that is able to do what I asked (librosa.feature.melspectrogram). It works pretty well.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for all your help. However, I found a new library called libROSA that is able to do what I asked (librosa.feature.melspectrogram). It works pretty well.